# Separated cookies for each tab geckofx c#

Tags: c#, gecko, geckofx

i want to use separated cookies for each tab and is there any possible to use proxy for each tab, i hope get any replay. Thanks

i tried with make another profile for each tab but it still share cookies between tabs .

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in a classic way. One instance of Xpcom (your application) uses one profile directory. You can only specify the path manually before calling `Xpcom.Initialize`, if you want:

```
string directory = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), Path.Combine("Geckofx", "MyFolder123"));
Xpcom.ProfileDirectory = directory;
```

The same is with the proxy, it can be set only for one instance of Xpcom:

```
GeckoPreferences.User["network.proxy.http"] = "123.0.0.4";
GeckoPreferences.User["network.proxy.http_port"] = 1234;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you need a separate instance of the program that runs the GeckoFx in order not to share the cookies (the user profile folder).